# What is the "QTL" library?

Tags: c++

In a question about forward declaring templates, and an answer that this is not possible doing manually for standard templates, a commenter says

> That's why I prefer QTL - I can write forward declaration for any template.

What is that "QTL"? I have never heard about it and google doesn't come up with something useful for me.

Comment: Do you have a link to that question? I vaguely remember seeing that and I believe the poster _might_ have been referring to Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that he meant Qt Template Library.

Answer (score 1):

In Genetics, QTL means Quantitative Trait Loci. It's a region of the genome which has been found associated to a quantitative trait for example blood pressure, wieght etc....

A QTL library is a library where all identified QTLs and the related information are saved and made available.

Hope that helps

nic

Comment: It is probably of better quality than Qt, which others mentioned. +1

Answer (score 0):

`QTL` is the Qt Template Library like already answered. For a comparison between `QTL/STL` check this link :

http://blog.codeimproved.net/posts/qtl-stl.html

The drawback of QTL if you do not already use `Qt` is that you should link your application with `Qt` dlls. In any case [`Qt`](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is a great open-source (LGPL) application/UI framework worth learning.